# Can i Create one table for purchases orders and sales orders?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm creating a Motorcycle store system, i wondering if i need to create one table that contains orders, the sales orders  and the purchases orders with a column that will be called OrderType that determine if its purchase order or sale order
the same with Payments, money that i pay to supplier and money that customer pay to me, should be in table that called payment and column that determine if its outgoing payment or income
is that ok? or i need to create other tables

Comment: Your single column suggestion is reasonable, absent any other information or data.

Comment: so its ok to be a null columns that regards to the purchase Orders like the FK purchaseOrdersId
in a sale order row @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider against it... Purchases are from a vendor YOU get the products from to build/fix/manufacture something.

Sales orders would have a customer you are selling to and thus would be foreign keys to different tables... unless your customer table has your vendors too and that has some column to identify difference as Vendor vs Customer.

Additionally, as you expand your design development and queries, purchasing history, etc., it may be more beneficial to have them separate.

Comment: i meant to create different column for each, like CustomerID and VendorID and make em nullable, and one of them gonna be null @DRapp

Comment: I tend to agree with @DRapp here. As your application evolves and expands in the future, you might find you add more and more nullable columns to cater for the differences between purchase orders and sales orders. I expect your future self would thank you for starting with a clean separation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single table.  Whether this is good design or unfortunate design depends on how you use the data.  How many times do you ever want to query these two datasets as if they were one dataset?   How many times to you query them separately?